# issue with $('selector') in jquery

Tags: jquery

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cars>
    <car company="TOYOTA">
        <product>Prius</product>    
    </car>
    <car company="TOYOTA">
        <product>New Fortuner</product> 
    </car>  
</cars>
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#car').click(function() {
            $.get('data.xml',function(data){
                $('#content').empty();
                $(data).find('car').each(function(){
                    var $car = $(this);
                    var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                    html += '<h3>' + $car.attr('company') + '</h3>';
                    $('#content').append(html);
                });                        
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="car">Car</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is taken from here: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-and-XML-P970.html

Question:

In index.html, `$(data).find('car').each`, how does this work: `$(data)`? usually I see `$('selector')`, such as `$('.class')`, `$('#id')`, but data is xml file here. could anyone explain this to me? thanks.

Comment: In the success callback, `data` is not an XML *file*, it's an XML *document root node*. Think how `$(document.body)` works - it's basically the same.

Comment: Or if `data` is a string of XML it works the same as `$("<div>Test</div>")`, i.e., it creates the elements for you (without adding them to the page). Although you're not really supposed to do that with XML, just HTML. Either way, it wouldn't hurt to read the [`$()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get('data.xml',function(data)
```

after u have made this call the entire xml content in data. so 'data' holds car tag.

then

```
$(data).find('car').each(function(){ ... })
```

looks for each 'car' tag within the data, i.e the xml content

FYI: *for better understanding use debugging tools like FIREBUG, and do a step by step analysis of your javascript code*

Comment: well, basically I want to know is: what is the difference between `data` and `$(data)`?

Comment: @user2507818: `data` is either a string or a DOM element and `$(data)` passes `data` to the jQuery function and returns a jQuery object. It's like asking "what is the difference between `42` and `foo(42)`".